# android activity only happens once but i need it to repeat

Tags: android, android-activity, repeat, oncreate, tabview

so my app has two tabs

tab 1 is a login page then

tab 2 is a user details

the user needs to loginfrom tab 1 then only details would load from tab 2 so if the user didn't login and goes to tab 2, an alertdialog would show the problem is, after going back to tab 1 and if the user does not login again prior to tab 2, the alertdialog would not show again. I'm not sure if I should use onRestart or onPause or something..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

the easiest way to do is to set the flag in the tabhost    `.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`

thanks for the help guys :D

Answer (score 0):

Change Your Application Flow.

make one tab represents a set of activity.

make use of activity group.

Comment: i will javanator! btw, the codes for the tab is as follows is there something i should change? ntent = new Intent().setClass(this, TabOne.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("main").setIndicator("Tab1",
              res.getDrawable(R.drawable.mainico))
              .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);